# Link that opens a folder on network drive

Tags: javascript, html, file

I've tried the approaches suggested on other questions that are similar, most notably:

```
file:///S:/ etc
```

I cannot get this to work it just fires the "Not allowed to load local resource:" error in the console.

I'm wondering is there any work around for this, that will actually allow me to open a network folder using a link

Any help appreciated

Comment: I think browsers have a built in security feature that blocks `file:///` requests over HTTP. I'm also interested in a work around for this, aside from using something like a static IP.

Comment: Yeah thats what i've found, just wondering if anyone has had any luck with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best thing i can find for this scenario, not ideal but it will have to do just now

Firefox extension required = https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/local-filesystem-links/
Chrome extension required = https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/locallinks/jllpkdkcdjndhggodimiphkghogcpida?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

IE works fine with no extensions